# Diferencias entre java.util.Date y java.sql.Date

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Quisiera saber cuál es la diferencia entre los objetos `java.util.Date` y `java.sql.Date`, además si estoy creando una aplicación utilizando **Hibernate JPA** cuál de estos objetos debería usar para guardar mis fechas.

Debo decir que mi aplicación funciona bien con ambos, hasta donde he podido probar, lo que quisiera saber es sí alguno de estos objetos tiene una característica de lo diferencie del otro.

Answer (score 3):

Es por la información que obtienes de cada una:

- **java.util.Date** = Representa un momento exacto hasta el milisegundo (2017 Septiembre 28 11:50:45)
- **java.sql.Date** = Representa solo una fecha (2017 Septiembre 28)

Generalmente usas java.sql.Date para formar el PrepareStatement, ya que la BD no aceptaría la info que provee java.util.Date.

Answer (score 0):

acorde con la javadocumentacion

1. java.sql.Date en una clase envoltorio(wrapper) que cubre los milisegundos , los cuales son utilizados por el JDBC para identificar un tipo de fecha en SQL.
2. java.sql.Date representa una fecha sin infor respecto al tiempo/hora mientras que java.util.Date representa ambos fecha y hora.
3. sql.Date es una clase heredad de util.Date.
4. ambas clases mutan(por ende son muy malas)